# 2005 Malibu stuck in park

Tags: transmission, malibu, gear-stick

I have a 2005 Malibu.

The gear-stick is stuck in park. I've tried using brute force to get the gear-stick to shift, but it won't move.

What's the cause/fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the handle on the gear-stick was loose.

There is a linkage inside the shaft of the gear-stick that gets pushed down when the driver presses the button on the gear-stick (unlocks the gear-stick).

The handle had become loose, due to the set-screw becoming partially unscrewed. This meant that the handle/button did not fully engage the linkage. So the gear-stick was not unlocking properly.

The solution was to screw the set screw back in -- which properly affixed the handle.

Problem solved; the gears shift properly now.

---

*It's likely obvious that I'm not a car guy; feel free to correct my terminology, etc.*

Comment: If it happens again, put some BLUE loc-tite on the set screw.